# firing order adjustment for 1.6 hdi engine after rebuil?

Tags: firing-order

I  have  a  grand  Picasso  1.6  HDI  9HZ  engine  recently  i  have  rebuild  the  engine  by  replacing  crankshaft  and  piston  rings  and    but  i  want  to  know  how  can  i  adjust  firing  order  to  put  on  timing  belt  ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is there an underlying problem you're trying to solve here? I'm not quite sure why you'd *need* to change the firing order? Or is the issue you need to change the overall timing? How do you know you need to change any of this? Why would changing out the crankshaft and piston rings make it any different than normal for putting a timing belt in place?

Comment: Do you need to time the camshaft to the crankshaft - is that what you mean?